# what is the right approach to pass default values in python extesnions?

Tags: python, python-c-api

How can i pass the default values to c extensions like 10,20 ,the below code doesn't take the 
values for a =10 and b =20. In below code  example.py is simple a python code which is calling the c function calculate .

example.py

```
def Multiply:
  calculate( a=10,b =20)
```

calculate.c extension file

```
if(! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii" ,&a, &b));

-----------some more code here ------
------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing parenthesis in the c extension file.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't default values; those are keyword arguments. As such, they're not going to be in the `args` tuple.

Instead, you probably want [`PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords).

Comment: could you share some example code for using above approach .I went through some code in python document But its not much clear

Comment: I am getting the error |"more argument specifiers than keyword list entries" when used PyARG_ParseAndKeywords().